# Html video background not working for iOS on Ionic framework

Tags: html, css, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get a full screen video background for my `Ionic` app, it works perfectly fine on Android and the Browser, but when I run the app on an iPhone in Xcode simulator, **It's just a white background and the video doesn't load.**

**Html Code:**

```
 <div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline webkit-playsinline>
      <source src="/assets/videos/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
 </div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.fullscreen-bg {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I've also added this in the config.xml file

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
```

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: Have you tried with the absolute 'native' path using `file:///android_asset/www/`?

Comment: Are you sure that video codec of your video work on ios?

Comment: _“Am I missing something?”_ - what have _you_ done so far to try and debug this …?

Comment: @johannchopin Ionic explicitly states to use the assets path that I posted, it works with every other resource (loading SVGs, JPGs, and other assets). *scaff* The mp4 uses h.264 codec, which is supported on iOS devices: https://i.imgur.com/lij4wwo.png  *CBroe* I've tried checking the Simulator system log, as well as the debug console within Safari but can't seem to find or produce any error messages regarding the video background.

Comment: Maybe try to add a position absolute to CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using UIWebView or WKWebView?  If you are using UIWebView I recommend you upgrade as it is no longer accepted by apple when you publish your app.

There is a lot of outdated information for both from ionic.  Make sure you are looking at the latest.

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

If you are using WKWebView, you should do the following:

Add ionic: to your content-security-policy's default-src and media-src entries. Do it on top of whatever you already have there.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content="default-src * 'self' ionic: data: gap: 
  https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
  media-src * ionic: 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Then in your *.component.ts get a local video URL that works by using

```
/*declarations*/
private win: any = window;
videoURL: string;

/* put this on onInit or a function you call to return your src
it will return "ionic://localhost/_app_file_/assets/videos/background.mp4"*/

this.videoUrl = this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc('/assets/videos/background.mp4');


/* then in your html*/
 <div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline webkit-playsinline>
      <source src={{videoUrl}}>
    </video>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem recently and the only way I have found is not clean and is temporary but it works. I use an iframe.

Here is my Ionic code

```
<div class="video">
    <iframe [src]='videoUrl'></iframe>
</div>
```

I call an iframe with an URL from my server which returns the video in HTML format. 
Here is the HTML rendering

[image]

By doing this, I have no problem on IOS.

This is of course a temporary solution, it would be much better to find a solution without going through an Iframe

Hope to help you